# Is there any way to get an exact match on ResolveNames calls

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to find email id of a user through `esb.ResolveNames(username)` function, but for some usernames, it returns multiple entries. Is there a way to restrict it to the exact match?

For example, if I want to find for **User1**, the Result I get is [**User1**, **User12**, **User123**]. I just need **User1**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure not given all of the details. One trick that you can try is using the `=` in front of the username, so it's like `=User1`. That should work if that corresponds to the first part of their email address.

Comment: This did not work for me. It returned the same results as `ResolveNames` without the `=`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I ended up using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to get the email per AD account:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, adName);
return user.EmailAddress;
```